# Group By data on the basis of Service Code and display data using Jquery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

What I want is, I want to group by Data based on `Service code` coming from datatable. I want to group by the selected value from the `datatable`.

Below is my Datatable screenshot

[image: Datatable]

In above picture I have checked four checkboxes. So I want to `groupBy` those 4 columns data based on the `Service Code`.

Suppose, the Service code for first two checked rows are `3297392` and for other two checked are `3293490` So it should display my datatable something like below

[image: Display Data]

With grouping it also is adding SAP ID column and ASSETS COUNT.

I am unable to get the exact logic for that, but something which I tried is like below

```
function ViewGroupBySummaryData() {

var tableToViewSummary = $('#confirmToFECertify');
tableToViewSummary.empty();

var table = $(dtCertifyEFO).DataTable();
var data = table.rows('.selected').data();   
}
```

In `data` I get the values of selected row but without columns.

The data is like below in console

`0:(14)[

   "",
   "<a class="   actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a>",
   "I-AP-APRR-ENB-B002",
   "INAPAPRRIDETTW6001",
   "GANESH NAGAR_AT2001",
   "",
   "3297392",
   "MAINTENANCE OF IP COLO ENODEB SITE / IP Colo",
   "ACTIVE",
   "12/11/2014",
   "",
   "Mahindra &amp; Mahindra Limited - 168888",
   "",
   ""
]1:(14)[

   "",
   "<a class="   actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a>",
   "I-AP-APRR-ENB-G001",
   "INAPAPRRYRNLNB6001",
   "VENUGOPAL NAGAR",
   "",
   "3297392",
   "MAINTENANCE OF IP COLO ENODEB SITE / IP Colo",
   "ACTIVE",
   "12/11/2014",
   "",
   "Mahindra &amp; Mahindra Limited - 168888",
   "",
   ""
]2:(14)[

   "",
   "<a class="   actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a>",
   "I-AP-BRYS-ENB-6000",
   "INAPBRYSBRYSTW6001",
   "Bukkarayasamudram",
   "",
   "3293490",
   "MAINTENANCE OF RCOM COLO ENODEB SITE / R-Colo",
   "ACTIVE",
   "12/11/2014",
   "",
   "Mahindra &amp; Mahindra Limited - 168888",
   "",
   ""
]3:(14)[

   "",
   "<a class="   actionIcon" id="discripancy"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i></a>",
   "I-AP-BRYS-ENB-6001",
   "INAPBRYSXXXXTW6003",
   "CHENNAMPALLE",
   "",
   "3293490",
   "MAINTENANCE OF RCOM COLO ENODEB SITE / R-Colo",
   "ACTIVE",
   "12/11/2014",
   "",
   "Mahindra &amp; Mahindra Limited - 168888",
   "",
   ""
]`

Please help me to build the logic using jquery datatable.

Below is my HTML

```
<table id="confirmToFECertify" class="myTable table table-striped table-bordered nowrap" cellspacing="0"></table>
```

Comment: But did u got what I m expecting here ?

Comment: Yes, I understood what you want. I want to have a snippet so that it can be easy for me to test using the API.

Comment: sure, give me few mins, i will create a js fiddle and let u know

Comment: Okay, I will have a look at it

Comment: @edkeveked: any issue or are u busy in something else ?

Comment: @edkeveked: please see my updated js fiddle for more info  https://jsfiddle.net/pjn75x9b/14/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190018/discussion-between-edkeveked-and-b-n).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach:

Display a new datatable and populate its rows with the code and the sum of selected elements. The code is not tested since the snippet does not really simulate the click event. `r[5]` (respectively `r[6]`) corresponds to the row of SAP ID and `assets count`. I can't really see the values of those fields in the console.log information you provided. You can change `5` and `6` to meet your table field position.

```
function ViewGroupBySummaryData() {

    var tableToViewSummary = $('#confirmToFECertify');
    tableToViewSummary.empty();

    console.log($(dtCertifyEFO));

    var table = $(dtCertifyEFO).DataTable();
    var data = table.rows('.selected').data().toArray();

    var newData = {};
    data.forEach(r => {
        var code = newData[r[6]]
        if (code) {
            // if the code is already present sum the value of each row
            newData[code] = [newData[code][0] + parsefloat(r[5]), newData[code][1] + parsefloat(r[7])]
        } else {
            // add new row corresponding to the code
            newData[code] = [parsefloat(r[5]), parsefloat(r[7])]
        }
    })
    // create new DataTable
    var t = $('#example').DataTable();

    // add rows to the new datatable
    Object.keys(newData).forEach(function(k) {
        var values = [];
        values.push(k);
        for ( var i = 0; i < newData(k).length; i++) {
          values.push(i)
        }
        t.row.add(values)
    })

    // display the new datatable

}
```

Comment: give me 5-10 mins will discuss on chat, as i have also implemented something

Comment: can we discuss now ?

Comment: I edited the code so that you can use it with an old version of js

Comment: Ok will check it tomorrow as I left for today